# Added Tree items won't show when tree view is expanded

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I have an application for iOS/android developed with Delphi XE8 FMX.

In the app I have a treeview with tree items. When I add a tree item to a node when that same parent node is expanded, then I need to either a) collapse and expand the parent node from the app itself or b) do that programmatically ( see below ) to get the tree item to show right away. I tried calling 'repaint', but that did not work. Is there a better work around? Sometimes when calling the collapseall, expandall like I do below, then some of the tree nodes become unresponsive ( non-selectable ) until after I first select the top most tree node.

```
procedure TnewForm.AddTreeItemClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  t:TTreeViewItem;
begin
  t:=TTreeViewItem.Create(nil);
  t.Text:=NewTreeItemEdit.Text;
  if TreeView.Selected<>nil then
  begin
    t.Parent:=TreeView.Selected
  end else
    t.Parent:=TreeView;
  //Treeview.Repaint;
  treeview.CollapseAll;
  treeview.ExpandAll;
  NewTreeItemEdit.Text:='';
end;
```

How can I make dynamically added tree items show right away without collapsing/expanding the treeview?

Comment: adding a begin update, end update surrounding it all fixed the unresponsive issue. Still, is there a more appropriate way of doing this?

Comment: wonder if https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.TreeView.TTreeViewItem.ImagesChanged (called on the new items after adding them) could help

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
procedure TnewForm.AddTreeItemClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  t:TTreeViewItem;
begin
  t:=TTreeViewItem.Create(nil);
  t.Text:=NewTreeItemEdit.Text;
  if TreeView.Selected<>nil then
  begin
    t.Parent:=TreeView.Selected
  end else
    t.Parent:=TreeView;
  //Treeview.Repaint;
  treeview.Selected := t;
  NewTreeItemEdit.Text:='';
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Dsm's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028054/757830) works, but changes the TreeView's selection. If you want the selection to remain unchanges, but instead just that the added item is instantly visible, then expand its parent:

```
procedure TForm1.AddTreeItemClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  T :TTreeViewItem;
begin
  T := TTreeViewItem.Create(nil);
  T.Text := NewTreeItemEdit.Text;
  if TreeView.Selected <> nil then
  begin
    T.Parent := TreeView.Selected;
    TreeView.Selected.IsExpanded := True;
  end else
    T.Parent := TreeView;
  NewTreeItemEdit.Text := '';
end;
```

Comment: Yes, it depends on what you want to do. Sometimes you want the selection to stay as it is and sometimes you want it to change to the newly added item.

Comment: well, I haven't tried this yet - I will shortly - but I don't think the issue is that my nodes are needing to be expanded when I have them added. If a node already has sub-nodes and is already expanded for example, if I then add another sub-node, which would presumably show right away, doesn't.

Comment: That's not the case on Windows. I can't test it in iOS nor Android.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem with Windows / XE8.
The workaround that did it for me:

```
  if Assigned(TV.Selected) then
    begin
      N := TTreeviewItem.Create(Self);
      N.Text := 'Another child';
      N.Parent := TV.Selected;
      N.IsExpanded := TRUE; // This seems to do the trick
    end;
```

Hopefully this will get attention in next releases.